# Can i use XCOPY to copy only files that have changed size?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I'm trying to use XCOPY to backup .PST files from Outlook and only backup files that have changed since last use.

Normally this would be easy using the /d switch to save only files with a newer modified date but Outlook changes the date when it's opened regardless of whether the contents have changed.

Is it possible to use an IF statement to compare file sizes and only backup if the file size is different (not necessarily larger or smaller)?

Currently using:

```
XCOPY /m /f /i /y c:\*.pst \\NetworkLocation\%USERNAME%\BACKUP
```

Thanks

Comment: What if _content_ changed keeping file _size_ unchanged?

Comment: Leave XCOPY and move on to [ROBOCOPY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx). It was designed to replace XCOPY and provides much more functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually is unbelievable that a tool for copying cannot "update" a target file. At least XCOPY cannot, and neither can ROBOCOPY AFAIK.
This batchfile is clumsy but gets the job done:

```
@echo off
:: copy files to TARGETDIR if different, modified date or size or name
set TARGETDIR=BACKUP
for %%f in (*.pst) do CALL :COPY_CHANGED %%f %TARGETDIR%
goto :EOF


:COPY_CHANGED
   set saved=(None)
   set live="%~1"
   if not exist "%~2\%~1" goto :DO_COPY
   rem compare file metadata of %1 in current dir and dir %2
   pushd "%~2"
   for /f "tokens=3 usebackq" %%a in (`dir "%~1" ^| findstr /C:"%~1" ^|^|  echo --- `) do set saved=%%a
   popd
   for /f "tokens=3 usebackq" %%a in (`dir "%~1" ^| findstr /C:"%~1"`) do  set live=%%a
   if "%live%".=="%saved%". goto :EOF
:DO_COPY   
   echo original: %live%
   echo backup:   %saved%
   xcopy "%~1" "%~2" /F /Y
   goto :EOF
```

You would need to adjust the XCOPY options to your needs. The `echo` lines in the subroutine can be deleted.
For each file, the batchfile collects the filesize once in the source folder and then in the destination folder and compares them literally, using `dir`. If equal the file is skipped else it is XCOPY'd.

Comment: Thanks, this works but I don't want it to compare the modified time, just the size. Is there a way to do this? I guess I would have to modify the line for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in (`dir "%~1" ^| findstr /C:"%~1" ^|^|  echo --- `) do set saved=%%a

Comment: Just replace `tokens=*` with `tokens=3`. I will edit my answer accordingly.